# Jquery change css of nested div

Tags: jquery, css

I am having a spot of bother with jquery and being a bit of a novice with it here's my problem:

I am making a drop down panel menu, Ive got the drop down ok but need to affect the background image of a div that is nested inside the div which is clicked to trigger the action. ie ".side_bar_top_text" is the div that's background needs to be changed.

jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.side_bar_top').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
      $('.side_bar .side_bar_panel', this).slideUp();
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');

    }
  });
});
 </script>
```

html:

```
 <div class="side_bar_top"><div class="side_bar_top_text">COMMERCIAL CONSTRUCTION</div></div>
 <div class="side_bar">
  <div class="side_bar_panel">
   /*the list of elements*/
  </div>
 </div>
```

All I need to do is change the background image of side_bar_top_text via css when the panel is up and vice versa.
I've tried various methods with no luck.
Can anyone help?

Comment: `$('.side_bar .side_bar_panel', this)` will never work. as you're searching for those elements WITHIN the `side_bar_top` and you close that element before `side_bar`, it should be `$(this).closest('.side_bar').find('.side_bar_panel')`

Comment: There is a css method call in jQuery [here](http://api.jquery.com/css/).  What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this help you? http://jsfiddle.net/jgQx3/2/

CSS:

```
.side_bar_top {
  background: url(path/file1.jpg);
}

.side_bar_top.active {
  background: url(path/file2.jpg);
}
```

SCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.side_bar_top').on('click', function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.toggleClass('active');
    $this.next('.side_bar').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="side_bar_top active">
  <div class="side_bar_top_text">COMMERCIAL CONSTRUCTION</div>
</div>
<div class="side_bar">
  <div class="side_bar_panel">
    /*the list of elements*/
  </div>
</div>
```

This function does not collapse already open options though.

Answer (score 0):

To get the element `side_bar_top_text` which is a child of the clicked element, do:

```
$(this).find('side_bar_top_text');
```

To change the background:

```
$(this).find('side_bar_top_text').css('background-image', '<your_image>');
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS:

```
.side_bar_top .side_bar_top_text{
    background:url(path-to-original-image.jpg); //whatever you want
}

.side_bar_top.active .side_bar_top_text{
    background:url(path-to-image.jpg); //whatever you want
}
```

But if you have a specific image for each or some other reason to do it in jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.side_bar_top').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');

    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
      $('.side_bar .side_bar_panel', this).slideUp();
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
      $('.side_bar .side_bar_panel', this).removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');

      $(this).find('.side_bar_top_text').css('background', 'url(path-to-image.jpg)');

    }
  });
});
```

Edit:

In css you can see that we override the background for active class. The original image is defined above.
This method requires jquery to add and remove the active class on click.

I added this line to your listener:

```
$(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
```

which should remove active for every sibling of the clicked element. That should restore your original image.

Comment: that's great. I've got it to change the image with css (jquery won't work this jquery method was one I already tried) but with the css method how do I get it to change to image back on toogle up?

Comment: I made an edit to my answer. jQuery will work on this, but if it is not doing what you want then it is likely a problem in how you wrote the listener. Check your console to see any errors.

Comment: Looks like the class active is not being removed. I have edited my original post to show code I'm now using. any Ideas?